# Detener consumidor cuando no puede conectar (Spring Boot + Kafka)

Tags: spring, boot, kafka

necesito ayuda para detener mi aplicacion cuando por ejemplo se desconecta por 10 min o en su efecto no puede conectarse al servidor.

```
    2021-08-16 18:39:21.927  WARN 15548 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest-] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
    2021-08-16 18:39:24.942  WARN 15548 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
    2021-08-16 18:39:24.943  INFO 15548 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler              : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1591961485, epoch=INITIAL) to node 1:
    
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
```

en el caso de que no pueda conectar al iniciar, seria igualmente en un plazo de 10 min.

```
2021-08-16 18:42:15.960  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-08-16 18:42:15.961  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-08-16 18:42:19.125  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-08-16 18:42:19.126  WARN 23068 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=topicTest, groupId=goupTest] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

En mi aplicacion uso ConsumerFactory y ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory para toda la configuracion del consumidor.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programacion).